# Dependency Injection to Handle Case When HttpContext.Current Doesn't Exist

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, nhibernate, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and in my Application_Start event I have the following code:

```
container.RegisterType<ISessionFactory>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(c => {
    return BuildSessionFactory();
}));
container.RegisterType<ISession>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager<ISession>(), new InjectionFactory(c => {
    return c.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession();
}));
```

The session factory (ISessionFactory) lives for the length of the application. The session (ISession) lives for the length of the ASP.NET request. I also dispose the session in the Application_EndRequest event. This allows me to inject the ISession throughout my application and it works as expected.

I'm now trying to build task scheduling into my application. I have added the following code into the Application_Start event:

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => {
    var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
        var service = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISomeService>();

        ...
    }));
    thread.Start();
};
timer.Enabled = true;
```

This should run every 5 seconds. The implementation of ISomeService injects the ISession in the constructor and I don't wish to change this class. My issue arises when it tries to resolve ISession as it tries to resolve it in a thread where HttpContext.Current is null and therefore an exception is thrown. I was wondering how I should register the session to handle this scenario. I'd appreciate the help.

Thanks

Here's my PerRequestLifetimeManager class incase it helps:

```
public class PerRequestLifetimeManager<T> : LifetimeManager {
    public override object GetValue() {
        return HttpContext.Current.Items[typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName];
    }

    public override void RemoveValue() {
        HttpContext.Current.Items.Remove(typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName);
    }

    public override void SetValue(object newValue) {
        HttpContext.Current.Items[typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName] = newValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve the ISessionFactory and manage the lifetime of the session yourself.

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => {
var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
    var service = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISessionFactory>();
    using(var session = service.OpenSession())
    {
        //do something with session
    }

    ...
}));
thread.Start();
};
timer.Enabled = true;
```

Edit:
Unity has a feature with multiple container instances that can have different configuration. That way you can have a different lifetimemanager configured for the "service"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However this would require me to change my service (ISomeService in the example given) which I can't do as this would require a lot of refactoring and also doesn't work when I do wish to cache the session per request.

Comment: Update: This actually worked a treat. I inherited my PerRequestLifetimeManager from the PerThreadLifetimeManager and call the base methods if HttpContext.Current returned null. That way it automatically works. Thanks for your help.